# Logging system activity in linux files

Tags: linux, logging, audit

I have to log all the operation that will be do to a specific file(s).

The tool *audit* is exactly what I need, but it writes in the log file a lot of other unusefull information about other files (system files).

Is it possible with *audit* to have the output of a specific watch file (/user/home/specific_file) in a specific log file (/var/log/audit/specific_file)?

Other tool similar to *audit*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

inotifywait command can spit out lots of info about what's happening to files and/or directories.

Comment: Unlike auditd, the inotify does not show info about uid/gid pid/ppid permissions etc